# Keras history callback loss does not match with console output of loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, history

I am Training a cnn in Keras at the moment.
Now I want to log the history of the training process for later visualizations, which I do with:

```
history_callback = model.fit(train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=EPOCH_STEP_TRAIN,
      validation_data=test_generator,
      validation_steps=EPOCH_STEP_TEST,
      epochs=NUM_OF_EPOCHS,
      callbacks=callbacks)

val_loss_history = history_callback.history['val_loss']
loss_history = history_callback.history['loss']

numpy_val_loss_history = np.array(val_loss_history)
numpy_loss_history = np.array(loss_history)

np.savetxt(checkpoint_folder + "valid_loss_history.txt", numpy_val_loss_history, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt(checkpoint_folder + "loss_history.txt", numpy_loss_history, delimiter=",")
```

The validation loss is saved correctly and matches exactly the output from the console.

But the loss values, which I store, do not match the output values from the console, while training. See here:

```
121/121 [==============================] - 61s 438ms/step - loss: 0.9004 - recall: 0.5097 - precision: 0.0292 - acc: 0.8391 - val_loss: 0.8893 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_acc: 0.9995
Epoch 2/3
121/121 [==============================] - 52s 428ms/step - loss: 0.5830 - recall: 0.1916 - precision: 0.3660 - acc: 0.9898 - val_loss: 0.5422 - val_recall: 0.3007 - val_precision: 0.7646 - val_acc: 0.9996
Epoch 3/3
121/121 [==============================] - 52s 428ms/step - loss: 0.3116 - recall: 0.3740 - precision: 0.7848 - acc: 0.9920 - val_loss: 0.5248 - val_recall: 0.3119 - val_precision: 0.6915 - val_acc: 0.9996
```

And output of history_callback.history['loss'] is:

```
0.8124346733093262 
0.4653359651565552 
0.30956554412841797
```

My loss function is:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1e-9):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f**2) + K.sum(y_pred_f**2) + smooth)

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return (1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred))
```

I also tried:

```
def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(1-dice_coef(y_true, y_pred))
```

Which didn't change anything.

Is there anybody out there, that can explain this weird behavior?

Comment: which is your tf version ?

Comment: tf version 2.4.1, nvcc version 11.2.142 and GPU is a RTX3090

Comment: @Nanex1011, Can you share complete code to replicate your issues, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2, unfortunately that's not possible, since it's code for a new research study, which is going to be published. But the given code snippets should include everything about the loss calculation, if I am right? I found out, the training and validation loss come closer with higher Epoch count. So..maybe the displayed loss in console is just for the last batch, whereas the written loss is the average over all batches? Something like that possible? At least, when I plot the validation loss against the train loss, qualitatively everything looks exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if I got the same issue.

What we have in common is **TF Version 2.4.1** (CUDA 11.2, Windows 10 Pro, Quadro T1000).

The issue disappeared when I trained the same network with the same data with TF Version 2.8.0 (CUDA 11.4, Debian 10, Tesla T4)

The only other thing we have in common is that we are both using CNNs.

Comment: In TF Version 2.12.0 same issue